# template matching vs feature matching for document image calssification

Tags: image, opencv, pattern-matching, emgucv, document-classification

To classify a large collection of various documents images, Usually two methods are used.
For achieve better performance these methods used GPU programming.

**First Method: based on template**

In this method, a fixed pattern is extracted from the image and other images are compared with it.
If the similarity is greater than a threshold value, the image will be correctly classified.

*code:*

```
GpuInvoke.MatchTemplate(source, template, imageresult, `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);`
```

> Problems of First Method:
>
> This method is not invariant to rotate more than 10 degrees. The
>   selected pattern in the image may be destroyed. (For example, damage
>   caused by punching the document.) If the pattern is too many, the
>   performance was reduced.

**The second method: based on image features**

In this way certain points of the image selected that are resistant to the changes.
If exist similar points in the other image, the image was classified.

*code:*

```
GpuBruteForceMatcher matcher = new GpuBruteForceMatcher(GpuBruteForceMatcher.DistanceType.L2);

matcher.KnnMatch(gpuObservedDescriptors, gpuModelDescriptors, gpuMatchIndices, gpuMatchDist, 2, null);
```

> Problems of Second Method:
>
> There are similar areas in other images with same feature vector. This
>   method have large False Positive A small change in the structure of
>   documents makes similar points were destroyed.

The first method has a high accuracy but for the characterization, has less efficiency.
The second method has low accuracy but for finding the right spots has high performance algorithm.

**Questions:**

To achieve best accuracy and efficiency focus on which method?
Is there a better approach to classify images of documents?

**Considerations:**

Because the resolution of document images is 100 dots per inch, using methods based on contour matching and OCR is not useful.
We use OpenCV or Emgu_CV library for image classification.
Images may be rotated more than 10 degrees.

*samples:*

[image: sample1]

[image: sample2]

Comment: What will be your classes? If the problem is rotation  can't you preprocess your images to correct for it?

Comment: @Miki The number of image classes is about 40, but there are many irrelevant images that may cause trouble.

Comment: I guess Bag od Words approach will be much suitable for your application. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/656906/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SURF-and-ORB-Feature

Comment: @Balaji R Does this method is useful for real-time applications?